# Could somebody please help me explain the grammar structure used in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, parsing

> Links **are created using** the  element which has an attribute called href.

I don't understand how they put "using" verb after "created". If it's a kind of reduced structure, how does it work?. Because I saw many times the term "created using" but I do not understand. Please help me and solve my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The element _is used to create_ the links. The links are created [by] using the element. Does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using the element which has an attribute called href* is a gerund clause functioning as an adverb, giving detail about the verb *created*.

Answer (score 0):

**Using certain elements** [noun phrase and subject] is quite difficult.

- Men are *seen* **fishing along the riverbank**.
- *Fishing along the riverbank* [noun phrase] is something he never does.
- The work **was done** *creating* a shell [noun phrase]
- Creating a shell [noun phrase] is easy.

**When you have a passive action verb, it can be followed by a noun phrase**.

- They **were silenced** *using a water gun*.
- We **were moved [affected]** *seeing the children play*.
- The children **were caught** *being themselves*.

which has etc. can be placed after the noun phrase:

Creating a shell **which works well** is easy.